# Trying to find an example of a real-valued functions that shares two or more values with its derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to find an example of a real-valued functions that shares two or more values with its derivative, but f' doesn't equal f. By sharing two values a and b, I mean f = a whenever f' = a, and f = b whenever f' = b. I know it's impossible for 2 meromorphic complex entire functions (that's what my paper's about) so I need a function that's differentiable once, and not analytic on C.

Comment: $f(x) = \sin(x)$ shares the values $a=3$ and $b=-17$ with its derivative, because both $f$ and $f'$ do not attain those values.